# Что такое типизация, присвоение типа?

Tags: java, c#, типизация, динамическая-типизация

Я правильно понимаю, что это что то вроде неявного наследования, допустим возьмем С#, в нем все классы неявно наследуются от класса Object, а тип int является классом `Int16, Int32, Int64`, то есть допустим при объявлении переменной `int x;`, мы создаем некий класс "х" который неявно наследует структуру класса Int, его методы, свойства и пр., а при инициализации создается сам объект, или например `Person p = new Person();`в левой части мы объявляем свою переменную-класс "р" которая явно наследует от класса Person, а в правой вызываем конструктор и создаем непосредственно сам объект. Поправьте меня если не правильно понял.

Comment: `тип int является классом` - нет, это примитив. Примитивы не имеют методов, к ним применимы математические операторы. У примитивов нет класса, хотя в Java 7 были добавлены классы-обертки.

Comment: `мы создаем некий класс х` - скорее, переменную с именем Х. И не класс это, а примитив

Comment: Советую почитать https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/49582/

Comment: [Eric Lippert: _Not everything derives from object_](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object/)

Comment: А что вы называете словосочетанием «присвоение типа»?

Comment: В питоне, например, даже "примитивы" являются объектами (a = 1, а - это объект и можно вызывать мотоды этого объекта). Но в Java это именно примитив

Comment: @SlandShow: В C# `int` — не объект, но вы вполне можете вызвать `1.Equals(2)`.

Comment: `переменную-класс "р" которая явно наследует от класса Person` "p" - это экземпляр класса, то есть некая копия содержимого, а в правой части с помощью оператора `new` выделяется под неё оперативная память

Answer (score 2):

Вы думаете не вполне правильно.

В языках наподобие Java или C# у вас есть типы-значения (в Java это примитивные типы, в C# структуры) и ссылочные типы (классы).

Так вот, объявление

```
int x;
```

просто *резервирует место* в памяти, где может храниться экземпляр `int` (то есть, 4 байта). При этом имя `x` ссылается на это место.

А вот код `x = 1` записывает на это самое зарезервированное место значение 1.

Для ссылочных типов это работает немного по-другому. Объявление

```
Person p;
```

резервирует место не под сам объект, а под *ссылку* на объект (если вы знакомы с C, это что-то наподобие указателя). А код

```
p = new Person();
```

создаёт этот объект, и в зарезервированное место записывает ссылку на созданный объект.

Comment: согласен int x; резервирует место в памяти, я имею ввиду что когда создается экземпляр int: int x = 1;, то этот экземпляр "наследует" методы структуры Int (в С#), такие как Equals(), GetTypeCode(), ToString()  и др. которые описаны в структуре Int. Структура Int в свою очередь "наследует" методы abstract class ValueType, который в свою очередь наследует методы от базового класса Object. Т.е. получается типизируя объект мы определяем его функциональность, поведение, разрешенные операции над ним которые определены в базовом классе Object и унаследованы от него, либо переопределены + свои методы.

Comment: Пример из С#: метод Equals(object) определен в базовом классе Object, далее он есть в базовом классе типов значений abstract class ValueType и наконец в структуре Int64. Или я че то перепутал?

Comment: к таким выводам пришел из анализа библиотеки mscorlib в Visual Strudio, в частности mscorlib/System/Int64/Базовые типы/ValueType/Object

Comment: @Ramil: Ну, ээээ. мы не можем «типизировать» объект. Мы создаём объект сразу нужного типа, после чего тип не меняется.

Comment: @Ramil: Ну да, метод `Equals` есть в `Object`, и переопределяется у `ValueType`. Но это вроде бы не имеет отношения к вопросу? Если объект имеет тип `int`, то он, разумеется, обладает всеми методами типа `int`, это само собой разумеется.

Comment: все, разобрался, спасибо

Comment: @Ramil: Вот и хорошо! Пожалуйста!